# Tensorflow: Object_detection: label_map_util AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am running tensorflow 2.7.0 and working on jupyter within `models/research/object-detection` directory. 
 However, while running below given code:

```
PATH_TO_LABELS = '/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)
```

I'm getting following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_30908/3716129084.py in <module>
      1 # List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
      2 PATH_TO_LABELS = '/data/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
----> 3 category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS, use_display_name=True)

C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in create_category_index_from_labelmap(label_map_path, use_display_name)
    229     {1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'dog'}, 2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'cat'}, ...}
    230   """
--> 231   categories = create_categories_from_labelmap(label_map_path, use_display_name)
    232   return create_category_index(categories)
    233 

C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in create_categories_from_labelmap(label_map_path, use_display_name)
    209     categories: a list of dictionaries representing all possible categories.
    210   """
--> 211   label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
    212   max_num_classes = max(item.id for item in label_map.item)
    213   return convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes,

C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in load_labelmap(path)
    130     a StringIntLabelMapProto
    131   """
--> 132   with tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid:
    133     label_map_string = fid.read()
    134     label_map = string_int_label_map_pb2.StringIntLabelMap()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'gfile'
```

Can anyone please help me out here!

Comment: Is it likely that the code is for TF 2.7, but the code snippet you are running appears to use:  tf.gfile.GFile(path, 'r') as fid .... ; In TF >= 2.0, tf.gfile.* is replaced by tf.io.gfile.*, therefore in the code it should be like: tf.io.gfile.GFile(path, 'r')

Comment: Even though, I change ```tf.gfile.GFile``` to ```tf.io.gfile``` in ```object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py```, error remains the same

Comment: I changed codes as Timbus suggested, but not working

Comment: @kem, change `tf.gfile.GFile` to `tf.io.gfile.GFile`, please refer to this [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/62e0d2597ec09873092e4fba1c2309e0/untitled166.ipynb) and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!